# Change each json object key(fn) value with number multiplied with 2

Tags: json, bash, shell, edit, jq

Hello I want to change each json object key value. JSON -

```
abc='[{"fn": 1,"name":"raimonds"},{"fn": 2,"name":"john"}]'
```

Now using some filter in jq -

```
res=$(echo "$abc" | jq 'map(if .fn then . + {"fn":22222} else . end)')
```

Now if I'm echoing $res it retuns -

```
'[{"fn": 22222,"name":"raimonds"},{"fn": 22222,"name":"john"}]'
```

I want to multiply each fn by 2 and output it like this -

```
abc='[{"fn": 22222,"name":"raimonds"},{"fn": 44444,"name":"john"}]'
```

How can i do that? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want different `fn` values for each object, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
res='[{"fn": 22222,"name":"raimonds"},{"fn": 22222,"name":"john"}]'
```

As [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) pointed out,
you could modify the object in a filter:

```
echo "$res" | jq '.[].fn *= 2'
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "fn": 44444,
    "name": "raimonds"
  },
  {
    "fn": 44444,
    "name": "john"
  }
]
```

My original suggestion was to construct objects with the modified property,
which would quickly get tedious, and has no advantages whatsoever:

```
echo "$res" | jq '[ .[] | {fn: (.fn * 2), name: .name} ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This filter multiplies the `.fn` member of each object within an array (or another object) by 2, leaving other members unchanged.

```
.[].fn *= 2
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/xFeICzxONW)